# Drupal 8 problems adding and extend asset libraries

Tags: php, drupal, yaml, assets, drupal-8

I try to build a Drupal 8 theme but I've got some trouble with the asset libraries.

The site stays white and the apache error log throws a php exception:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\\Core\\Asset\\Exception\\InvalidLibrariesExtendSpecificationException: "The specified library "radweiser/main-style" does not exist." at /Users/****/Sites/dev/radweiser/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Asset/LibraryDiscoveryCollector.php line 168
```

I'm using the bootstrap Drupal 8 Theme as my base theme.
Here are my yml files of my theme called radweiser:

radweiser.info.yml

```
name: radweiser
type: theme
description: Drupal 8 Theme
version: 0.1.0
core: 8.x
base theme: bootstrap
screenshot: images/screenshot.png
libraries:
- radweiser/global-styling
- radweiser/main-style

libraries-extend:
  bootstrap/base-theme:
    - radweiser/main-style

regions:
  navigation: 'Navigation'
  navigation_collapsible: 'Navigation (Collapsible)'
  header: 'Top Bar'
  highlighted: 'Highlighted'
  help: 'Help'
  content: 'Content'
  sidebar_first: 'Primary'
  sidebar_second: 'Secondary'
  footer: 'Footer'
  page_top: 'Page top'
  page_bottom: 'Page bottom'
```

radweiser.libraries.yml

```
global-styling:
  version: VERSION
  css:
    theme:
      styles/global.css: {}

main-styles:
  version: VERSION
  css:
    theme:
      styles/main.css: {}
```

Anybody knows the problem?

Comment: Hi, You use the current --dev version of Drupal core?

Comment: I'm using 8.0.1 stable

Answer (score 0):

It was just a typo

main-style / main-styles